# How to create a custom button in the ribbon of Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Please anyone can help me understand,

How to create a custom button in the ribbon of Tridion. I need to have a functionality later on click of that button.

Answer (score 8):

Some good tutorials on getting started creating Tridion GUI extensions:

- http://yoavniran.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/setting-up-a-tridion-gui-2011-extension-in-8-steps/
- http://www.curlette.com/?p=279
- http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/nononsenseguide
- http://tridionfanboy.wordpress.com/category/javascript/
- http://www.curlette.com/?p=401

There are also plenty of existing extensions to be found on [SDL Tridion World](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/index.aspx) that serve as great material for studying. Finally: never underestimate the power of studying the source of Tridion's GUI yourself. The JavaScript parts are readily readable on your disk and (if you [disable the default JavaScript minification](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/DeactivateJSMinifier)) also in your browser.