# Tridion UI on Dynamic Page

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I have created a Page Dynamically which query the broker database and and based on filter displays the component presentation on run time. I have used Tridion UI on the page to edit the components.

Now as the content on the Page is Dynamic, I do not want to use the "Create and Insert Content" functionality as it will create the component and it will try to insert that on Page which I don't want here.

Is there any way so that I can disable the "Insert Content" and "New Page" functionality for the page using dynamic CP's?

All I want is to in able the "Create Content" which uses required Content Type.

Answer (score 3):

Buttons in Ribbon Toolbar has associated command with it. By click on the Button, Command will be invoked. There exists a supported way of extending existing Commands. So you can create Commands extensions for Insert Conter and New Page Buttons, which will override "isEnabled" method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there in no out of box functionality to disable these option on any specific template type. You may need add GUI Extn to disable these option.

Answer (score 1):

Meenakshi. You can disable and/or hide these buttons/functionality with config settings. As Vikas points out, in terms of disabling them within a specific context you'll have to look at a GUI Extension of some sort that, on presenting the interface checks the context of the page/cps and acts accordingly.

This link contains some good points of reference for GUI Extensions in general.: [How to create a custom button in the ribbon of Tridion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560300/how-to-create-a-custom-button-in-the-ribbon-of-tridion/11560652#11560652)